# Amplify Storage Exception: Failed to fetch identity ID in Android

Tags: android, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-android, amplify-auth-cognito

I have followed the docs and imported the S3 bucket successfully in Android Project, but I'm not able to upload or download from the bucket. I even removed the storage and auth using amplify cli, added new storage with auth and guest having all the access and auth with default params. Even then I'm facing same issue! What have I done wrong? Or what should be changed to make it work?

Below is the error log:

```
StorageException{message=Failed to fetch identity ID, cause=null, recoverySuggestion=AuthException{message=Failed to get identity ID. Check if you are signed in and configured identity pools correctly., cause=null, recoverySuggestion=Sorry, we don't have a suggested fix for this error yet.}}
                                                                                                        at com.amplifyframework.storage.s3.configuration.StorageAccessLevelAwarePrefixResolver.resolvePrefix(AWSS3PluginPrefixResolver.kt:70)
                                                                                                        at com.amplifyframework.storage.s3.operation.AWSS3StorageUploadFileOperation.start$lambda-1(AWSS3StorageUploadFileOperation.kt:89)
                                                                                                        at com.amplifyframework.storage.s3.operation.AWSS3StorageUploadFileOperation.$r8$lambda$_oyIiFAO5jakjMzA-FOjDISO9dI(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at com.amplifyframework.storage.s3.operation.AWSS3StorageUploadFileOperation$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:4)
```

Comment: Did you find something? ia ma also facing the same error.